# PHP COPY Function is not working

Tags: php, html, file, copy

```
$filename =  "../literature/apolloseries1700263589.pdf";
$newfilename = "../literature/new_apolloseries1700263589.pdf";
if (file_exists($filename)) { // This Work 
        if(copy($filename, $newfilename)) { // This Not Working  
            echo "Copy Success";
        } else { 
            echo "Copy Failed";
        }

     }
```

hello my copy function is not working on my server.please anybody help what the problem with it.

thanks

Comment: have you any error please check you have allow_url_fopen=on in your php.ini

Comment: You are trying to dereference a null pointer at line 525.

Comment: yes allow_url_fopen is ON ...

Comment: there is no any error its shows just show COPY FAILED

Comment: Maybe u haven't permission to write in literature folder.

Comment: yes thanks there was folder permission error ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the user which runs the php script doesn't have enough rights to write in this folder.

You'll need to give this user the folder, in a terminal run :

```
chown [user] ../litterature
```

[user] being the user which runs your php script (usually apache or www-data), you can have its name using : `ps aux` in the terminal and checking for the line with httpd, or apache / apache2...